# how to manage images in emacs org mode

Tags: images, emacs, imagemagick, org-mode, image-editing

I am considering switching from zim wiki to org mode for managing collection of web page pieces. Typically it includes images and texts I copied from a web browser. The question:

1 how to insert mixed image and text from clipboard? like automatically download image to the note folder and make the link.

2 how to delete the image files once I've deleted the note?

Thank you!

Comment: did you find a solution?